# Question regarding iPhone core data and how to duplicate features for multiple users...that doesn't make sense, just read my question :)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, object

So I am working on a simple iPhone app, that uses core data to manage objects. My code is similar in function to Apple's CoreDataBooks app, found [here](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/samplecode/CoreDataBooks/index.html). There is a blank UITableViewCell, and you have the ability to add objects to this blank list. If you hit the add button, a DetailViewController pops up that manages the attribute of each object. In the coredatabooks example, the app is like a library, and you can add book objects. My question is about how I might go about making it so that multiple users can have their own separate list of these objects. Again, relating back to coredatabooks, you would be able to make different library objects whose attributes are the book objects themselves. So using the convenient and easy to use coredata ui, would it be very hard to set it up so that in the UITableView, there was Library-A and Library-B and then selecting one of the libraries would move me to a screen that has the list of different books unique to that specific library? If you then select a book, you would then be able to view that book's attributes as before. So I guess my question is regarding how to put another RootViewController-esque view in front of the native one. As you may gather from this post I am in the learning stage of iPhone development, so I don't even know if logically this is even feasible or the correct way to do it. Any help/insight on this matter would be greatly appreciated! Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another UITableViewController (.h, .m, .xib files). And you can put some functionality into that view controller for adding library.

You can set that viewcontroller as startup object from MainWindow=.xib file. OPen that xib file -> expand navigation controller -> click on root view controller.

then in attributes window you can select your new controller as startup. you have to also set startup class from identity window.

Answer (score 0):

Ruchir is correct, you can add another table view and controller. You will have to make some adjustments so that it is loaded and displayed first.

Also, it sounds like you will want to create a new entity in your data model for a Library which should have a to-many relationship with the Book entity.

Library <-->> Book

The new table view controller can use a fetched results controller that fetches Library entities. When the user chooses a row, you can set a property on the books table view controller before you push it on the navigation stack. Then use a predicate on the books fetched results controller to only fetch books in that library.